# How to play the WoW trailers?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

World of Warcraft: Cataclysm removed the original trailer videos from the

```
\Data\Interface\Cinematics
```

and replaced them with a single

```
\Data\Interface\Cinematics\WoW3X_Intro_1280.avi
```

How do i play this video file<sup>1</sup>?

The video is 1280x720, compressed with `PMVX` (`{30355844-0000-0010-8000-00AA00389B71}`).

---

### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> Outside of World of Warcraft

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [.avi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_Video_Interleave) file contains a media type I am unfamiliar with: "PMVX", according to VLC media player.  I could not open this file in any of the video formats mentioned below:

- [Media Player Classic](http://mpc-hc.sourceforge.net/)
- [VLC Media layer](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/)

I do, however, have other copies of these in a different installation folder.  Instead of:

> C:\Program Files\World of Warcraft\Data\Interface\Cinematics

as you have mentioned, have you tried you installation language folder? For me this is enGB:

> C:\Program Files\World of Warcraft\Data\enGB\Interface\Cinematics

Within this folder, I have each intro in 800 and 1024, as well as the Wrathgate cutscene, which I believe covers what you were looking for.

Comment: Just because it has an extension .avi does not mean it's an .avi file.

Comment: @Viper_Sb, You turned out to be right in the end, it is not an .avi file of the kind I am familiar with.

Comment: This answer helps me, although won't help anyone joining since Cataclysm - or anyone looking to access the Cataclysm trailers. The localized cinematics (e.g. **enUS**, **enGB**) folder seems to be leftover from earlier versions. In my case i was really only interested in vanilla and Wrath trailers. And although my question still stands (i.e. how to play `PMVX` files), and it's something i'd still need: i have the answer i need for now. Accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Various World of Warcraft cinematics are available to view on the [WorldofWarcraft Youtube Channel](http://www.youtube.com/user/WorldofWarcraft).

This of course does not answer your direct question on how to view the files that are part of the installation, but does allow you to watch the cinematics outside of WoW.

Answer (score 0):

Well we know the format is coded differently then the others, best I could come up with for the abbreviations is (Moving Picture Experts Group Video Xclusive) or (Movie Picture Video Xclusive) Which doesn't make since since Xclusive actually starts with an E. Im thinking it might be a compressed file.